# JNI: How to delete temporary dll file on exit

Tags: java, dll, java-native-interface

I have a program that uses JNI. When the program starts, it extracts the required dll file into the temporary directory. However, when I call

```
deleteOnExit();
```

on this file, it does not delete when the program exits. I know this is because the dll file is still being used, so is there an alternative solution? Note that I don't mind using languages like VBScript to accomplish this.

I do not want to permanently install the dll because I'm using this to write an installer.

Comment: Err, don't delete it? Install it properly in the first place?

Comment: I want the user to never notice that there was a dll in the first place.

Comment: You can't. While your application is running, he can notice.

Comment: The user can notice, I'm just saying that he shouldn't have to know about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry yeah unload the dll first, you can't delete it before unloading it, but it is better to avoid deleting and copying dlls, the following can go wrong:

- If you have multiple instances of your application running deleting and copying dlls will be interfering with one another
- If your application crashes the dll will not be deleted
- Some anti-virus programs will not like your application deleting and creating dlls

Instead use an installer, you can also turn your java application into an .exe and then place the dlls next to it. If the dlls are in a (pre-defined location not sure if I understand you there) the you will need to add that location to the PATH variable before running the application.

Comment: The reason I'm using the dll is to write an installer in the first place. I'm using System.nanoTime() for the file name, along with File.createTempFile().

Comment: Look your question is not clear. Do you want the installer to delete itself? A program cannot delete itself... It can maybe start a process which will delete it in 20 seconds, and close down before the delete takes place so the delete will be successful. So it could run a batch file in another process with a call "timeout /t 30" and then a "del yourdll.dll" But if the dll is in the temporary diretory it will get deleted in due course anyway and you don't need to do this....

Comment: When does the temporary directory get cleaned?

Comment: It works by timestamps I'm pretty sure, but this sort of thing differs on different OSs. I imagine there would also be stratergies employed for when your disk space starts to get really big or your temp files space is getting ridiculous. But I guess the answer to your question should be it doesn't concerne you, but that it will be delete eventually.                EDIT: Sorry I am incorrect, sometimes they will just stay there like on windows, but utilties like clean up disc storgage ect will clean it for you, but anyway again it comes down to not deleting or copying them in the first place.